# How do you simulate the Windows Start Menu being selected and unselected with MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()?

Tags: java, cursor, point

I am creating a Java program simulating Windows 95. I found the Start Menu exceptionally difficult to program with Swing package, therefore I declared JLabel ImageIcon Objects which represent the Start Menu in different situations. (If there is a good way to program the Windows Start Menu with inherent Swing objects, please tell me)

For example:

The first image is the Start Menu open with no item selected.

[image]

The second image is the Start Menu open with "Shut Down..." Selected.

[image]

I tried to use the MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() method to obtain the X and Y coordinates of the mouse cursor. Before that, I measured the X and Y coordinates with the following code. After obtaining results from it, I reached the conclusion that between java.awt.Point[x=4,y=630] and java.awt.Point[x=287,y=680], "Shut Down..." in the Start Menu should be selected.

```
 while (true) {
   try {
     Thread.sleep(2000);
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
 }
```

But the following code failed to work. I would like to achieve the following effect: when the mouse cursor is between java.awt.Point[x=4,y=630] and java.awt.Point[x=287,y=680], the first image turns into the second image. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
//Desktop
    JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    //Start Menu Open
    JLabel startMenuOpen = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("StartMenuOpen.png")));
    startMenuOpen.setBounds(-155, 195, 600, 600);
    //Start Menu Open When "Shut Down..." is Selected
    JLabel startMenuOpenShutDownSelected = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("StartMenuOpenShutDownSelected.png")));
    startMenuOpenShutDownSelected.setBounds(-155, 195, 600, 600);

    Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    double x = point.getX();
    double y = point.getY();
    if (x > 4 && x < 287 && y > 630 && y < 680 && startMenuOpen.getParent() != null) {
      desktop.remove(startMenuOpen);
      desktop.add(startMenuOpenShutDownSelected);
      desktop.revalidate();
      desktop.repaint();
    }
```

Comment: You need to place the code that checks the position inside a timer, another thread, or an event, otherwise, it will only run once when your code is first launched. Note: Don't place the code in a while loop because it will just lock up your application (Use another thread, a timer, or respond to mouse movement events). Possibly helpful: [Detect Mouse Move Event On JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861895/detect-mouse-move-event-on-jpanel). If you want more code please provide more detail.

Comment: @sorifiend Thanks. FIrst I need to learn how to use a timer.